# grep returns No such file or directory

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to grep the IPs by using this command but I get an error `No such file or directory`.

```
cat sub.txt | xargs dig {}+short | grep -Po ([0-9]){2,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}
```

Comment: sub.txt contain subdomains and i want to extract only the ips

Comment: Always put regexes in single or double quotes, like `grep -Po '([0-9]){2,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}'` - Also please show some examples of what's in `sub.txt` and what you expect your output to be.

Comment: Please add sample input (`sub.txt`) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment here).

Comment: @KhalidAl-Anzi Put the relevant information in the question. Show us a few lines of the actual content in `sub.txt` and what you expect to get out from it if my suggested change doesn't work.

Comment: `gooogle.com`
`1.google.com`
It contain subdomains and the output should be 129.234.213.12 only ips

I'm just adding " double quotation and now it works ^^

`grep -Po "([0-9]){2,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}"`

Comment: @KhalidAl-Anzi [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71344672/edit) the question and put the relevant information in the question in the future.

Comment: Round and curly braces have special meaning to the shell. You must quote the arguments, so that the shell doesn't interpret them. Also, I bet that the line with the error message says a bit more than only _No such file or directory_. Always post the complete error message - better posting too much than posting not enough.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the complete job:

```
dig -f sub.txt +short
```

See: `man dig`

Comment: I'm just adding " double quotation and now it works ^^ grep -Po "([0-9]){2,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}"

Comment: @KhalidAl-Anzi ... but this answer solves the problem much safer and simpler. Your `grep` will find IP:s if it finds one listed in the `dig` metadata too.

Comment: There's no need for `cat`, `xargs` and `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just adding " double quotation after the -Po and now it works ^^

`grep -Po "([0-9]){2,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}"`

Comment: `xargs dig {}+short` should be `xargs dig {} +short` too.

Comment: There's no part of the script that you need the shell to interpret that would require you to use double `"` instead of single `'` quotes. Use single quotes by default, double if you need them, and none if you need that - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.